# What is Ubuntu Advantage doing on my (fully supported) 18.04 box, what is it checking for twice a day, and can I get rid of it?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-advantage

Doing a little light reading in my server's `/var/log/` directory today and found some logs I'm not familiar with - `ubuntu-advantage.log`.

The log has repeating contents like this

```
2021-08-01 03:25:21,947 - ua_update_messaging.py:(347) [DEBUG]: Updating UA messages for APT and MOTD.
2021-08-01 03:25:21,947 - util.py:(419) [DEBUG]: Reading file: /etc/os-release
2021-08-01 03:25:21,994 - util.py:(419) [DEBUG]: Reading file: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
2021-08-01 03:25:21,994 - config.py:(442) [DEBUG]: File does not exist: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
2021-08-01 03:25:22,008 - util.py:(419) [DEBUG]: Reading file: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
2021-08-01 03:25:22,009 - config.py:(442) [DEBUG]: File does not exist: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
2021-08-01 15:34:22,023 - ua_update_messaging.py:(347) [DEBUG]: Updating UA messages for APT and MOTD.
2021-08-01 15:34:22,036 - util.py:(419) [DEBUG]: Reading file: /etc/os-release
2021-08-01 15:34:22,080 - util.py:(419) [DEBUG]: Reading file: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
2021-08-01 15:34:22,080 - config.py:(442) [DEBUG]: File does not exist: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
2021-08-01 15:34:22,096 - util.py:(419) [DEBUG]: Reading file: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
2021-08-01 15:34:22,096 - config.py:(442) [DEBUG]: File does not exist: /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/private/machine-token.json
```

It looks like every 12 hours it wakes up, looks for something on my system, does not find it, and goes away.

I don't remember installing anything called `ubuntu advantage` on purpose and from what I can tell, it's used for systems that are past their EOL, which this 18.04 system is decidedly not.

The first log dates from this May.

Also, I can't find a service called `ubuntu advantage` or an entry in `cron`.

What is this thing trying to to do, how is it running, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Comment: Seems to resemble bug [LP# 1929123](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-advantage-tools/+bug/1929123)

Comment: @user535733 thanks, that's informative. Fortunately it's not segfaulting on my system, just consuming resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After running upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS I was [very](https://pad.lv/1928604) [surprised](https://pad.lv/1928531) with Ubuntu Advantage Tools installation and ESM existence.

I do not need its [enterprise-oriented functionality](https://ubuntu.com/advantage).

So we can simply remove Ubuntu Advantage Tools by

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

then reboot and enjoy.

Comment: I tried that, but stopped because it also wanted to remove `ubuntu-minimal` metapackage.

Comment: Removal of [ubuntu-minimal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/ubuntu-minimal) is safe, it is just meta-package. I'm currently running about five 18.04 LTS systems without this package installed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know what triggers the script to run? I could not find it in cron or anywhere. I hate to say they were being sneaky but....

Comment: Really I do not know (maybe, yet). I'm avoiding things which make Ubuntu to act like Window$ 10. So I usually remove both ubuntu-advantage-tools and unnattended-upgrades from systems which are managed by me.

Comment: I agree with your approach on this! I removed the metapackage from most of my systems. I had to mark a few packages as manually installed on one of them, but glad to be rid of this useless ubuntu-advantage thing.