# What is Ubuntu Advantage doing on my (fully supported) 20.04 box, what is it checking for twice a day, and can I get rid of it?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-advantage

This is an update of [What is Ubuntu Advantage doing on my (fully supported) 18.04 box, what is it checking for twice a day, and can I get rid of it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357656/what-is-ubuntu-advantage-doing-on-my-fully-supported-18-04-box-what-is-it-che) for 20.04, **because the answer is different**.

Re: ubuntu-advantage-tools, looks like every 12 hours it wakes up, looks for something on my system, does not find it, and goes away.

I don't remember installing anything called ubuntu advantage on purpose and from what I can tell, it's used for systems that are past their EOL, which this 20.04 system is decidedly not.

Also, I can't find a service called ubuntu advantage or an entry in cron.

What is this thing trying to to do, how is it running, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: If it's just the answer that's different, then why not edit that question to make it more general, and post your answer there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This fine [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1357716/243321) works great for 18.04.

It tells you to remove the package which is great because on 18.04 it only removes the additional package `ubuntu-minimal`.

However, on 20.04 it wants to remove a lot more stuff, namely

- `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
- `ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk`
- `update-manager`
- `update-manager-core`
- `update-notifier`
- `update-notifier-common`

because of the following dependency tree:

> ```
> $ aptitude why ubuntu-advantage-tools
> i   ttf-mscorefonts-installer Depends update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2)
> i A update-notifier-common    Depends update-manager-core (>= 1:17.04.2)      
> i A update-manager-core       Depends ubuntu-advantage-tools
> ```

That's unacceptable, so we have to look for another way. And here it is.

1. Stop and mask the services

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop ua-messaging.timer
   sudo systemctl stop ua-messaging.service
   sudo systemctl stop ua-timer.timer
   sudo systemctl mask ua-messaging.timer
   sudo systemctl mask ua-messaging.service
   sudo systemctl mask ua-timer.timer
   ```
2. Check that it worked

   ```
   systemctl status ua-messaging.service
   systemctl status ua-messaging.timer
   systemctl status ua-timer.timer
   ```

   You should see a status like this for each

   > ```
   > $ systemctl status ua-messaging.service
   > * ua-messaging.service
   >     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit ua-messaging.service is masked.)
   >     Active: inactive (dead)
   > $ systemctl status ua-messaging.timer
   > * ua-messaging.timer
   >     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit ua-messaging.timer is masked.)
   >     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2021-11-12 23:10:16 GMT; 1min 2s ago
   >    Trigger: n/a
   >
   > Nov 12 01:09:42 focal systemd[1]: Started Ubuntu Advantage update messaging.
   > Nov 12 01:10:16 focal systemd[1]: ua-messaging.timer: Succeeded.
   > Nov 12 01:10:16 focal systemd[1]: Stopped Ubuntu Advantage update messaging.
   > $ systemctl status ua-timer.timer
   > * ua-timer.timer
   >     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit ua-timer.timer is masked.)
   >     Active: inactive (dead)
   >    Trigger: n/a
   > ```
3. Remove the APT hook (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1374989/66509) for details why)

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
   ```

and after a day or so check `/var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log` to confirm it is not running any more.

Comment: Maybe `systemctl mask` would be better than `systemctl disable` for 100% guarantee :)

Comment: @N0rbert you could well be right, I don't understand the difference between the commands well enough to say.

Comment: On my system, the timer and service is called `ua-timer.timer` and `ua-timer.service` - but I believe they have the same function?

Comment: You can load a disabled service. A masked one you can not

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have edited your great answer to reflect latest finding from https://askubuntu.com/a/1374989/66509 .

Answer (score 0):

Moar nukes for whoever (has to) install the latest `python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk`, bringing in `ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon`:

```
sudo rm /etc/ubuntu-advantage/help_data.yaml
sudo rm /etc/update-motd.d/88-esm-announce
sudo rm /etc/update-motd.d/91-contract-ua-esm-status
sudo systemctl mask esm-cache.service 
sudo systemctl mask reboot-cmds.service
sudo systemctl mask apt-news.service
```

*Source: `.../ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.13.2~20.04.1_amd64.deb`*