# How to get rid of ubuntu-advantage-tools without destroying system

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, systemd

How can I remove package ubuntu-advantage-tools  in lubuntu focal or disable its services? I do not need it

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-advantage-tools 
[sudo] password for alex: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  distro-info* lubuntu-update-notifier* ubuntu-advantage-tools* ubuntu-minimal* update-manager-core* update-notifier-common*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 4.801 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Note all packages I marked as manual installed.

The most systemd services are static from this package.

I disabled ua-timer.timer

```
systemctl is-enabled ua-timer.timer 
disabled
```

Is this enough?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate? [What is Ubuntu Advantage doing on my (fully supported) 20.04 box, what is it checking for twice a day, and can I get rid of it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371014/what-is-ubuntu-advantage-doing-on-my-fully-supported-20-04-box-what-is-it-che)

Comment: For me halve answered. I know what it is doing, but I had to admit I did not read the whole post when I ask.   I would prefer I could complete remove it without removing meta packages. this can give a bad awaking during an `apt autoremove`

Comment: I believe disabling the timer is the most "sane" option - I've thought about removing it myself. But as you say since it's included in the `ubuntu-minimal` metapackage, I fear this will give headaches along the way. On my system, I've disabled `ua-timer.timer`and `ua-timer.service`.