# What is the definition of a "standard security update"? What other classifications are possible?

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

Since recently upgrading to 20.04 I see informational messages after running `apt update` similar to

```
46 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
31 standard security updates
```

Googling has failed to turn up the definition of the phrase `standard security update`.  What is it?  And, are there `non-standard security updates`?  What possibilities are there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems to a part of `ubuntu-advantage-tools` to distinguish between freely available security updates (standard) and ESM (paid, later, actual for 16.04 LTS).

May be removed by removing special UA hook by

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf
```

Above will transform

> ```
> 42 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> 29 standard security updates
> ```

to normal traditional behaviour

> ```
> 42 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> ```

All this UA ESM stuff on supported Ubuntu versions smells like big BUY word with capital letters.
I found this unacceptable. Especially the viral behavior of UA:

> ```
> $ sudo apt autopurge ubuntu-advantage-tools
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>  distro-info* python3-debconf* ubuntu-advantage-tools* ubuntu-mate-core* ubuntu-mate-desktop* ubuntu-minimal* ubuntu-release-upgrader-core*
>  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk* update-manager* update-manager-core* update-notifier* update-notifier-common*
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
> After this operation, 6 687 kB disk space will be freed.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
> Abort.
> ```

I have reported a [bug 1950692](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-advantage-tools/+bug/1950692) about `ubuntu-advantage-tools` "integration".

---

Clues:

- http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/update-notifier/update-notifier_3.192.30.9/changelog :

  > update-notifier (3.192.30.7) focal; urgency=medium
  >
  > - data/apt_check.py:
  >   ...
  >
  >   - Make distinction between standard security updates and ESM updates
  >     when performing package counts. (LP: [#1926208](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/1926208))
- https://git.launchpad.net/update-notifier/tree/data/apt_check.py#n254
- https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-advantage-client/blob/0e971e09ca30f21d581c0e8273579e892d198920/features/attach_validtoken.feature#L95

Comment: Just to confirm, I dug up an old 16.04 VM that has ubuntu advantage enabled on it. Instead of `standard security updates` it says `26 esm-infra security updates` Well done!

Answer (score 1):

You're right about standard security updates. Those are delivered in the Ubuntu Main respository for the initial 5 years of any Ubuntu LTS release. For example, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS benefits from it until 2025.

The ESM security updates are indeed in a different category - they go beyond standard security updates. The access requires a subscription, but it doesn't  necessarily mean that you will have to pay anything. Anyone can get a free subscription for personal use.

To subscribe: https://ubuntu.com/advantage
To learn more: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/09/ubuntu-16-04-security-updates-esm-for-free

Full disclosure, I am a product manager at Canonical.

Comment: How about giving us a simple way to turn ubuntu advantage off for supported systems? Stopping it is turning into a game of whack-a-mole.