# Does removing 20apt-esm-hook.conf disable security updates before ESM period starts?

Tags: apt, updates, ubuntu-advantage

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1374989/1638775), it says removing `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf` makes the upgrade summary go from:

> ```
> 42 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> 29 standard security updates
> ```

To the ESM-free version:

> ```
> 42 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> ```

Before ESM kicks in, is there a difference here in what is installed? i.e. are the 29 "standard security updates" included in the 42 installed or is it in addition to them? I don't want to interface with anything related to Ubuntu Advantage but only getting a subset of security updates when the OS is still officially supported is a no-go as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your Ubuntu system is in Standard Support, there is no difference.

Differences will only appear on an LTS system after the end of Standard Support.